# AdBlock filter not working

Tags: adblock

On some sites I use there is an overlay ad, with an URL like `//furied.com/script/ut.js?cb=` with random numbers after `cb=`.

If I try to block it with a filter like `||furied.com/script/ut.js^$domain=example.com` (with `$domain=example.com` so the filter only works on example.com domain) it works, while if I try with `//furied.com/script/ut.js?cb=`, `||furied.com/script/ut.js?cb=`, `||furied.com/script/ut.js^cb=` or any variation like these it doesn't work.

I tried also using regex, like `||furied.com/script/ut.js?cb=\d+`, but it doesn't work; I'm wondering if regex works only on AdBlock Plus, since the help page AdBlock redirects to is about AdBlock Plus.

Even something broad like `||com/script/*.js?cb=$domain=example.com` doesn't work, while `||com/script/*.js$domain=example.com` does.

How can I make `||furied.com/script/ut.js^cb=` work, if possible?

I'm on Windows 10 19042.1237, using Chrome version 94.0.4606.61.

Comment: OS and browser would help us.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I updated the question; Chrome version 94.0.4606.61, Windows 10 19042.1237.